# Crossdomain all from GAE

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc

How to make a cross-domain call from GWT?
I found JSONPRequestBuilder as a solution, but it can only create GET request not POST. I am trying to call URL shortner service ("http://goo.gl/api/shorten") of google.

Comment: Maybe you mean 'from gwt'? not 'not servlet'?

Comment: I have tried com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder; but it failed throwing "Internal Server Error" com.google.gwt.xhr.client.XMLHttpRequest.create()Lcom/google/gwt/xhr/client/XMLHttpRequest;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it through URLFetch. Below is my code:

```
//Classes to import
import com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod;
import com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest;
import com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse;
import com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService;
import com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceFactory;


//Shortening download URL
URL url=new URL("http://goo.gl/api/shorten");
HTTPRequest req=new HTTPRequest(url,HTTPMethod.POST);                               
req.setPayload(("url=www.google.com").getBytes());

URLFetchService  service = URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService(); 
HTTPResponse response = service.fetch(req); 
byte[] content = response.getContent(); 
String urlshort=new String(content);   //here is the JSON data from goo.gl
```

Answer (score 1):

From servlet on GAE you can call external http services via [URLFetch](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/overview.html).

From client side GWT you can directly call Google Shortener API via gwt-google-apis. See the [shortener example](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/GoogleAPIsSamples#Google_URL_Shortener_%28goo.gl%29_API) at the end of page.